# horizontally scroll a ul with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tools

How can I horizontally scroll a ul by using the mouse cursor? Basically I would like to emulate the bottom section of [this](http://www.tn3gallery.com/examples/default/) image gallery. I have found a javascript method online, but it is not nearly as smooth.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, your method was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var $div = $('div');
var $ul = $('ul');

// width of div
var width = $div.width();

// width of ul - width of div
var ulWidth = $ul.width() - width;

$div
    .on('mouseenter', function(e) {
        // get left offset of div on page
        var divLeft = $div.offset().left;

        $(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            var left = e.pageX - divLeft;
            // get percent of width the mouse position is at
            var percent = left / width;

            // set margin-left on ul to achieve a 'scroll' effect
            $ul.css('margin-left', -(percent * ulWidth));
        });
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        // remove mousemove event
        $(window).off('mousemove');
    })
;​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aarongloege/gQyz6/

You basically need to position the ul element based on the mouse position's percentage from the left of the viewport (div in my example).

Answer (score 0):

Check out these two existing jQuery plugins that do exactly what you're looking for:

1) http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller

2) http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/